# Datepicker no funciona

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

nuevamente preguntando sobre datepicker con Bootstrap
Resulta que perfectamente aparece el calendario pero las opciones que le doy parece que a duras penas reconoce el formato. El resto lo pasa de largo y en especial necesito bloquear fechas anteriores a la que menciono. Gracias.

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="datePicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <script src="datePicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="datePicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <script>

    $('#fecha_ini').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startDate: "15/10/1996",
        endDate: "15/01/2017",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        language: "es",
        todayHighlight: true
    });


  </script>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
        <input type="text" id="fecha_ini" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola estas realizando las pruebas en Firefox?

Comment: Sí, igualmente en Chrome

Comment: En Firefox no funciona correctamente, te debería deshabilitar los días fuera del rango de fecha, pero si te permite verlos, `datePicker` de bootstrap si debería funcionar correctamente en Chrome. Por eso pregunte donde estas realizando las pruebas

Comment: Gracias, sin embargo en ninguno de los dos funciona :( Es decir, no deshabilita los días

Comment: ¿Cuál es el comportamiento esperado?

Comment: Para que funcione como lo tienes debes cambiar `$('#fecha_ini').datepicker({` por `$('.input-group.date').datepicker({`

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad alguna respuesta? De ser así, márcala como aceptada para ayudar al sitio a mantener la buena salud por efecto de preguntas resueltas :D Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta seleccionar una fecha anterior al 15 de octubre de 1996 y no se puede, intenta seleccionar una fecha posterior al 15 de enero y tampoco se puede. Este es el código:

```js
  $('#fecha_ini').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startDate: "15/10/1996",
        endDate: "15/01/2017",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        language: "es",
        todayHighlight: true
    });
```

```html
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="datePicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <script src="datePicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <!--Esta fue la linea que agregué --->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    
    <script src="datePicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>
    <!--Y esta otra también--->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <input type="text" id="fecha_ini" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

Dejando el código como tu lo tienes, es decir que al lado del campo fecha salga un icono sería:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startDate: "15/10/1996",
        endDate: "15/01/2017",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        language: "es",
        todayHighlight: true
    });
  });
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="datePicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <script src="datePicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <!--Esta fue la linea que agregué --->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    
    <script src="datePicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>
    <!--Y esta otra también--->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
        <input type="text" id="fecha_ini" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

El problema que se generaba es porque usaste intercambiado los selectores de Jquery.

La respuesta que agregó **fredyfx** es la otra forma de acceder al campo fecha, es decir elimina los `div` y la etiqueta `span` para el icono